# Incorrect encoding on Php file but not on Html file

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I write this code in Html file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15" />
  </head>
  <body>
    Try with special character (ì)
  </body>
</html>
```

When I display my html file it's all ok

`Try with special character (ì)`

But when I rename my html file in php file this is the result

`Try with special character (�)`

Someone can help me to understand?

Comment: Try with; charset=UTF-8

Comment: I had try, but it's no resolve the problem

Comment: sometimes the editor you're using messes the characters up, make sure the encoding used by the editor is a suitable one

Comment: I set the same encoding from the text editor. The result don't change

Answer (score 0):

You could try with UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: I had try, but don't change the result

Comment: Are you using notepad? because i did try with it and get the same result as you. Try using another editor like sublime.

Comment: Also try rewriting the code in the new editor (don't paste). I just got the same problem and solve it by that.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the character encoding for the HTML document:

character_set   Specifies the character encoding for the HTML document.
Common values:

UTF-8 - Character encoding for Unicode
ISO-8859-1 - Character encoding for the Latin alphabet
In theory, any character encoding can be used, but no browser understands all of them. The more widely a character encoding is used, the better the chance that a browser will understand it.

To view all available character encodings, look at [IANA character sets](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml).

You just replace the below html:

```
   <html>
      <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
      </head>
      <body>
        Try with special character (ì)
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Don't change the result

Comment: I think you have missed something because that was the issue. Please refresh you page by cntrl+f5

Comment: Add this to the header in your php file and let me know if it solves or not -
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ?>

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PHP function [mb_internal_encoding](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-internal-encoding.php). It sets the character set that PHP will use internally. If you add this at the top of your HTML:

```
<?php
  mb_internal_encoding("iso-8859-15");
?>
```

Your HTML should show fine if the file is in ISO-8859-15. What happens is that PHP interprets the HTML looking for PHP blocks and generates the output based on the default internal encoding. In combination with `mb_http_output()` you can have a source file in one encoding, generating output in a different encoding.

Comment: And if you add `mb_http_output("iso-8859-15");`?

Comment: And using `Latin-9` instead of `iso-8859-15`? Or maybe `Windows-1252`? Also, which version of PHP are you using?